# Routing an event through multiple classes in C#

Tags: c#, events, routes

A common scenerio we are running into with our current application is where we need to route and event through several classes.

Here is a sample class heirarchy.

ActionManager
MainWindow
PresentationManager
MenuManager
Menu
MenuButton

The Menu subscribes to the click event of a MenuButton.  It then creates a CustomAction object and raises an event that is subscribed to MenuManager.  In the MenuManager event handler it in turn raises an event that is subscribed to by the PresentationManager, and so on.

Here is a sample of what is implemented for the PresentationManager:

```
    void MenuManager_ActionGenerated(object sender, CustomActionEventArgs e)
    {
          if (ActionGenerated != null)
                ActionGenerated(sender, e);
    }
```

I was hoping that there would be a way that I could raise the event at the Menu level and receive it at the ActionManager level.

Is it bad practise what I am currently doing?

Comment: See this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/vblasberg/archive/2010/03/30/wpf-routed-events-bubbling-several-layers-up.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also look into Event Aggregator. A good example can be found at codeproject: [Event Aggregator with Specialized Listeners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/52810/Event-Aggregator-with-Specialized-Listeners)

Answer (score 0):

If what you've listed as your class hierarchy is actually your visual tree, it sounds like what you are describing is Routed events.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx

Personally, I get scared by having a lot of events.  If you are not careful with unsubscription, they can extend the lifetime of your objects.   Also, they may cause tight-coupling, reducing testability.  In some cases using a Commanding pattern is a better approach.

Comment: I have run into issues in the past with objects being held onto for two long do to event handlers, a bad leak in .NET.

Comment: Same concept as event aggregator.  Build in Commanding in WPF - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx.  A lot of frameworks (like Prism) have an Event Aggregator pattern built in.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this  [CSharpMessenger Extended](http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=CSharpMessenger_Extended).

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `SubscriptionManager`.

By simplifying can be a `Dicationary<string, List<Action<...>>>`.
The key is the `event-name`, value is the `List` of `Action`s to run wen that even was raised.

So all yuor components subscribe to some specified event by adding its `Action<..>` to the list of specified event.

And when the even raised (always via `SubscriptionManager`) all `Action<..>`s from the list will be executed.

Just a basic idea. To make this production ready you need to code a bit more.

Good luck.

Comment: Is this similar to Event Aggregator that GuyVdn mentioned?  The ActionManager is really a dispatcher that queues actions and then passes them down for execution.  Originally we looked at making this a singleton that all of our action generating objects could call directly, but then I figured this make it tightly coupled.

Comment: @WPFNewbie: don't know `Event Aggregator`, but form the first look *seems* similiar. The difference is that here there are not `Publichers`. All events are hard coded into `SubscriptionManager`. What about tight coupling: every event has a delegate/action associated to it. It's in that way even now. So I don't see a problem in having this kind of structure.

Comment: I was refering to if we made our Action Dispatcher class a singleton that each item accessed directly and placed their action on the queue.  The Action Dispatcher would then dispatch it, kind of like a router for events.  This would require that each class know about the Action Dispatcher class, making it tightly coupled.

Comment: @WPFNewbie: well, how you gonna avoid tight coupling with ordinary events? If your type gonna be *affected* by some event or the type itself should "wait" for it, or some other class that manages routing.